# Docker - communicate between two containers

Tags: docker, containers, docker-container

I am new to docker environment and trying to figure out how to make two container communicate with each other.
I have two running containers. Container 1 is having a inference engine running which performs inference on image it receives. Container 1 is listening on port 9001. Container 2 is having the image and wants to send it to Container 1, but is failing saying

```
port 9001 is already binded to some service
```

PS When I try to send the image from host to container 1, it works fine, but I cannot understand on how to achieve the same from another container. Any help would be really grateful. Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to bind two services to the same socket, which is something you can't do. What docker commands are you running exactly?

Comment: You can use the docker compose to make two containers communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker-compose. It will create a bridge network for you when running the command `docker-compose up`, Each image defined in the Compose file will get launched in this network automatically.

If you are not using Docker-Compose and running individual container than expose both services port with the host.

docker run -p 9001:9001 image_1

docker run -p host's_port : container_port  image_2

Then can to communicate using host IP 
Like:
http://hostip : port